# Why training error varies with value of K in KNN?

Tags: machine-learning, knn

Why does the training error increases with value of K in KNN algorithm?

For k=1, training error is zero because if we take a point and determine 1st nearest neighbour it will be same point in the training dataset so error is zero. 
The same concept should be true for k=2, 3.... so on. 
Then how come training error increases with value of K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For k=1, the algorithm will choose a training sample which is closest to the test sample, since test sample is there in the training sample it will choose itself, and error will be zero, also overfitted model.
Whereas when k = 2, k=3 or greater it will look for those many numbers of neighbors which can belong to different groups, and hence error rate increases.